# Can't use SharedPreferences in method that doesn't get called in onCreate()?

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

In my app, I'm trying to save an ArrayList of Strings. I have an Activity Favourites, which has an `add()` method. This method is called in another Activity to add something to the ArrayList. I want that each time something is added, it first gets all the values that I've stored in `SharedPreferences`, checks if the value isn't already there and if it's not, adds it to the ArrayList. Finally I want it to store all the values again in `SharedPreferences`. When the Activity Favourites is called, it shows a list with all the favourites (Gets each value in database and all that).

So I've made a method, but as `onCreate()` is never called when an item is added to the ArrayList, I can't seem to instantiate my `SharedPreferences`. Is there anyone who can give me some hints to get this to work?

Note: I don't want to work with SQLite database, because it would be for only one class in my app, and it would contain very little values.

Also, the code I used:

```
public void add(String v, String k){
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int countvaca = prefs.getInt("vacacount", 0);
    int countkantoor = prefs.getInt("kantoorcount", 0);

    for(int i = 0; i <countvaca; i++){
        vaca.add(prefs.getString("Vaca"+i, null));
    }
    for(int j = 0; j <countkantoor; j++){
        kantoor.add(prefs.getString("Kantoor"+j, null));
    }

    boolean blnFound = vaca.contains(v);
    System.out.println("Does arrayList contain vacature ? " + blnFound);
    if(!blnFound){
        vaca.add(v);
        kantoor.add(k);
    }

    Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    countvaca = vaca.size();
    countkantoor = kantoor.size();
    edit.putInt("Vacaturelijstgrootte", countvaca);
    edit.putInt("Kantoorlijstgrootte", countkantoor);
    for(int a = 0; a<countvaca; a++){
         edit.putString("Vaca"+a, vaca.get(a));
    }
    for(int b = 0; b< countkantoor; b++){
        edit.putString("Kantoor"+b, kantoor.get(b));
    }
    edit.commit();


}
```

Comment: Have you some kind of error message? Than it's probably best to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If onCreate never gets called then you activity is never started, so the "this" in

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

doesn't refer to a properly initialized activity.

Either you should start your activity that contains your "add" method (which automatically calls the onCreate method), or you can pass a reference to the currently active Activity to your add method, i.e. something like this:

```
public void add(String v, String k, Activity a){
     prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(a);
```

However, it is not considered good programming style to directly call methods from one activity to another.
Best is to create a separate class that contains the code that the two activities have in common.

Comment: Well, I added an constructor with the Activity, based on your logic. Now I want to add a `Toast` as well, to notify if the item already exists. I've also instantiated the `Toast` just like the SharedPreferences, but It doesn't work. Do you know what's going on? Thanks already for your given answer!

Comment: What's the code for creating the Toast message? And what's the error message?

Comment: I've solved it already by calling the Toast in the previous Activity. There it's called in onCreate() with no problem.
Thank you for your intrest anyway!